# Option 'importsNotUsedAsValues' is deprecated and will stop functioning in TypeScript 5.5. in nextjs with Mongodb

Tags: typescript, mongodb, next.js, node-modules

When I try to connect with MongoDB and do the `db.collection.find` in page.js.

There are many Module not found errors coming up when I start and browse the application.

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'mongodb-client-encryption' in
Module not found: Can't resolve 'aws4'
Module not found: Can't resolve '@mongodb-js/zstd'
Module not found: Can't resolve 'kerberos'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js
./node_modules/mongoose/index.js
./app/utils/database.ts
./app/model/page.tsx
```

However, the error disappears if I use [nextjs API route](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/api-routes) to wrap the MongoDB code.

Why? Is there any problem when I use Mongodb in my page.js?